# How to execute custom logic at pyspark window partition

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe in the format shown below, where we will have multiple entries of `DEPNAME` as shown below, my requirement is to set the `result` = Y at the `DEPNAME` level if either `flag_1` or `flag_2`= Y, if both the flag i.e. `flag_1` and `flag_2` = N the result will be set as N as shown for `DEPNAME`=personnel

I am able to get the desired result using joins but I am curious if we can do it using window functions as the dataset is quite huge in size.

```
+---------+------+------+-+------+
|  depName|flag_1|flag_2| result |
+---------+------+------+-+------+
|    sales|    N|  Y    |  Y    |
|    sales|    N|  N    |  Y    |
|    sales|    N|  N    |  Y    |
|personnel|    N|  N    |  N    |
|personnel|    N|  N    |  N    |
|  develop|    Y|  N    |  Y    |
|  develop|    N|  N    |  Y    |
|  develop|    N|  N    |  Y    |
|  develop|    N|  N    |  Y    |
|  develop|    N|  N    |  Y    |
+---------+-----+------+ +------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

This looks like a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag_1 = 'Y' or flag_2 = 'Y'
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as result
```

For the updated version:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when flag_1 = 'Y' or flag_2 = 'Y'
                then 'Y' else 'N'
           end) over (partition by depname) as result
```

Comment: It should be at a partition depname level, if any flag is Y then set all rows for that partition as Y else N.

Comment: @nilesh1212 . . . It is rude to invalidate answers by changing the question.  The better approach is simply to ask a new question.  However, I have updated the answer with a version that does what you specify.

Comment: Yes sorry for that I understood from the comments that users are failing to understand the question (mistake at my end ) hence I updated the question, the 1st version of question didn't echo what I meant to say.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PySpark (since you included it in the tags) and say that your dataframe is called `df`, you can use

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('depName')

df = df\
  .withColumn('cnt', F.sum(F.when((F.col('flag_1') == 'Y') | (F.col('flag_2') == 'Y'), 1).otherwise(0)).over(w))\
  .withColumn('result', F.when(F.col('cnt') >= 1, 'Y').otherwise('N'))

df.show()

+---------+------+------+---+------+
|  depName|flag_1|flag_2|cnt|result|
+---------+------+------+---+------+
|  develop|     Y|     N|  1|     Y|
|  develop|     N|     N|  1|     Y|
|  develop|     N|     N|  1|     Y|
|  develop|     N|     N|  1|     Y|
|  develop|     N|     N|  1|     Y|
|personnel|     N|     N|  0|     N|
|personnel|     N|     N|  0|     N|
|    sales|     N|     Y|  1|     Y|
|    sales|     N|     N|  1|     Y|
|    sales|     N|     N|  1|     Y|
+---------+------+------+---+------+
```

Basically, within each partition determined by `depName`, you count how many times the condition `flag_1 == 'Y' | flag_2 == 'Y'` occurs, and you store it in `cnt` for all rows of that partition.
Then, you use a simple `.when` indicating with `'Y'` all groups that have `cnt >= 1`.

Comment: I need to do it at depName partition level, if any of the flag column is Y. It will set result as Y for that depName partition. Not at a row level

Comment: @nilesh1212 It wasn't clear in the previous version of your question. I've updated my answer now.